# Unable to run "apt upgrade" on ubuntu 18.04 --systemd-shim error

Tags: apt, package-management, 18.04, python, dpkg

I have recently upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 from ubuntu 14.04(via 16.04).

This is the error I see whenever I run `apt upgrade`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:

  libcloog-isl4 libcolord1 libelfg0 libisl10 libisl15 libmpfr4 libsox2 python-xapian python3-pycurl

Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.

The following packages have been kept back:

  amd64-microcode curl findutils initramfs-tools initramfs-tools-bin libcurl3 libsane-common libunwind8 mailutils mailutils-common openssh-client openssh-server openssh-sftp-server plymouth plymouth-theme-ubuntu-text python-pip python-pip-whl ssh

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 18 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.

After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y

Setting up systemd-shim (6-2bzr1) ...

dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: old-conffile **'debian/systemd-shim/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf'** is not an absolute path

dpkg: error processing package systemd-shim (--configure):

 installed systemd-shim package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1

Errors were encountered while processing:

 systemd-shim
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

The issue seemed close to this [one](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/systemd-shim/+bug/1773859) and few others

But the fixes don't work. I think it mainly because of this

> dpkg-maintscript-helper: error: old-conffile **'debian/systemd-shim/etc/dbus-1/system.d/org.freedesktop.systemd1.conf'** is not an absolute path